# Select/Deselect All dynamic checkboxes in Rails 4 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, haml

I have followed this StackOverflow Question's **[Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585572/select-all-deselect-all-checkboxes-in-a-page)** and **[Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606222/select-deselect-all-checkboxes)**

but not getting result.. As I am calling all checkbox list's data from `Range` tabel. and their id is also defined by data.. Let me show you the code for this screenshot

[image]

```
= f.collection_check_boxes :range_ids, Range.active, :id, :name, {},:class=>'checkbox'
```

which returns as

```
<input id="campaign_range_ids_1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="campaign[range_ids][]">
<input id="campaign_range_ids_2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" name="campaign[range_ids][]">
<input id="campaign_range_ids_3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" name="campaign[range_ids][]">
<input id="campaign_range_ids_4" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" name="campaign[range_ids][]">
```

I want if `All` means `id="campaign_range_ids_4"` is selected/deselected then all other check-boxes should be perform accordingly..

Here also have a screenshot of **Range Table**
[image: range table]

I had tried this Javascript

```
:javascript
  $('#campaign_range_ids_4').click(function() {
       if(this.checked) {
           $('#campaign_range_ids_1').checked = true;
           $('#campaign_range_ids_2').checked = true;
           $('#campaign_range_ids_3').checked = true;
           });
       } else {
           $('#campaign_range_ids_1').checked = false;
           $('#campaign_range_ids_2').checked = false;
           $('#campaign_range_ids_3').checked = false;
           });
       }
    });
```

Please correct me where I do Mistake.... Thanks in advance.. :)

### Updated Question

I have followed **[Shridhar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630578/select-deselect-all-dynamic-checkboxes-in-rails-4-with-javascript#answer-24630749)** and **[Pavan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630578/select-deselect-all-dynamic-checkboxes-in-rails-4-with-javascript#answer-24630888)** answer it works perfectly but now I want that when I select All then deselect any one then it must uncheck "All" (4th checkbox) but it remains as it is..

Comment: You have given the `id` wrong.It should be `$('#campaign_range_ids_4')` not `$('#campaign_beacon_range_ids_4')`

Comment: Thanks Pavan but still not getting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying **[Sridhar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630578/select-deselect-all-dynamic-checkboxes-in-rails-4-with-javascript#answer-24630749)** answer finally I got the Answer of my Updated Question's.

I wanted if `All`(4th checkbox) is `checked` then all check-box should be selected and if it's `unchecked` then all check-box should be `unchecked` it works perfectly

**But** Issue I had found that If `All`(4th checkbox) is selected then it check all boxes then if I unchecked any check-box then `All`(4th checkbox) must be `uncheked` which was not occur.

**Solution by Modifying Code:** In future if other people face the same issue..

***HTML Code:***

```
<input id="campaign_range_ids_1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="campaign[range_ids][]">London
<input id="campaign_range_ids_2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" name="campaign[range_ids][]">India
<input id="campaign_range_ids_3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" name="campaign[range_ids][]">USA
<input id="campaign_range_ids_4" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" name="campaign[range_ids][]">All
```

***JavaScript:***

```
$('#campaign_range_ids_4').click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#campaign_range_ids_1,#campaign_range_ids_2,#campaign_range_ids_3').prop('checked', true);

    } else {
        $('#campaign_range_ids_1,#campaign_range_ids_2,#campaign_range_ids_3').prop('checked', false);
    }

});

$('#campaign_range_ids_1,#campaign_range_ids_2,#campaign_range_ids_3').click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        } else {
            $('#campaign_range_ids_4').prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```

### [Working Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/eKHFb/14/)

Answer (score 2):

As i said,it should be `$('#campaign_range_ids_4')` not `$('#campaign_beacon_range_ids_4')`

This will work too

```
$('#campaign_range_ids_4').click(function() {
   if(this.checked) {
       $(':checkbox').each(function() {
           this.checked = true;                        
       });
   } else {
      $(':checkbox').each(function() {
           this.checked = false;                        
       });
   } 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pavan28/P4p7X/)**

Comment: By mistake I wrote $('#campaign_beacon_range_ids_4') then correct then also not worked...

Comment: Thanks Pavan...for your kind help 1+ for this  :)

Comment: I am finding another issue... it works fine with select/deselect All but when I select All then deselect any one then it must uncheck "All" (4th checkbox) but it remains as it is..

Answer (score 1):

Error in Selectors ,It should be `$('#campaign_range_ids_4')` not `$('#campaign_beacon_range_ids_4')` use `prop()` to set the checkbox state

Try this

```
$('#campaign_range_ids_4').click(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#campaign_range_ids_1,#campaign_range_ids_2,#campaign_range_ids_3').prop('checked', true);

    } else {
        $('#campaign_range_ids_1,#campaign_range_ids_2,#campaign_range_ids_3').prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eKHFb/10/)

OR

```
$('#campaign_range_ids_4').click(function () {
    $('#campaign_range_ids_1, #campaign_range_ids_2, #campaign_range_ids_3').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eKHFb/11/)

Comment: I am finding another issue... it works fine with select/deselect All but when I select All then deselect any one then it must uncheck "All" (4th checkbox) but it remains as it is..

Comment: I have solved the issue sorry to bother, check my answer... ;)

Answer (score 0):

change the selector to `$('#campaign_range_ids_4')`and do this:

```
$('#campaign_range_ids_4').change(function() {
    $('#campaign_range_ids_1, #campaign_range_ids_2, #campaign_range_ids_3').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

instead of `click` use `change` method.

Comment: Glad you got help from SO.